# How to do like compare on case sensitive string

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, case-sensitive

```
select http_host,user_agent,date,path, count(*)
FROM "public"."bus_request" 
where app_name = 'yyyy' and event_type <> 'browser_js' 
    and date <= GETDATE() and date>= GETDATE()-14 and request_score <> '80' 
    and path  '%login%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1_CS_AS

group by http_host,path, date, user_agent
order by http_host,date,count desc
```

I am getting error: SQL Error [500310] [42601]: Amazon Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "COLLATE" 
Position: 239;

Comment: Missing `LIKE`.

Comment: I added the `amazon-redshift` tag based on the error message. If you are using a different Amazon database service, then please change it

Comment: `and path  like '%login%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1_CS_AS` most probably

Comment: still getting - Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "COLLATE" 
Position: 243; i added the like i forgot and still same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default should be *case sensitive*, as explained in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/pattern-matching-conditions.html):

```
path like '%login%'
```

For case-insensitive, use `ilike`:

```
path ilike '%login%'
```